# hyperledger iroha set config files and gas fee

Tags: json, hyperledger, hyperledger-iroha

Am testing out iroha got it to function using the docker image, I did not clone the example repository cause there where many *.config files and *.sample files I did not understand which is for what, so I just created one file config.docker and added this in it.

```
{
  "block_store_path" : "/tmp/block_store/",
  "torii_port" : 50051,
  "internal_port" : 10001,
  "database": {
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "some-postgres",
    "port": 5432,
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "mysecretpassword",
    "working database": "iroha_default",
    "maintenance database": "postgres"
  },
  "max_proposal_size" : 10,
  "proposal_delay" : 5000,
  "vote_delay" : 5000,
  "mst_enable" : false,
  "mst_expiration_time" : 1440,
  "max_rounds_delay": 3000,
  "proposal_creation_timeout": 3000,
  "stale_stream_max_rounds": 2
}
```

My question is **block_store_path** required when using a database will it be used to store the db in the docker volume, also the *entrypoint.sh* what is it for and can it be used with docker containers cause how can you pass irohad Flags like **-drop_state** or **-reuse_state**.

Iroha out the box does not support gas fees for transactions but is it possible using the Hyperledger Burrow or some other method to get to do so